# How to UnitTest JdbcDAOs in Spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-test

Our team just inherited a Spring-boot application (R1.4.3) which has the following pom.xml (excerpt):

```
<groupId>SpreadSheetUploadWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpreadSheetUploadWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <db2.driver.version>10.5.9</db2.driver.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.6</tomcat.version>
        <poi.version>3.15</poi.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5 spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/bluecost
spring.datasource.username=db2admin
spring.datasource.password=db2admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

All of the Unit Test cases use the JDBC connection to the database, which requires the dB to be up and running (with the right schema) to make the test cases work, which is a pain.   How do we swap the implementation of the test context to another type of db - like HSQLDB?

I've read in the documentation that S-boot can auto configure HSQLDB, all we have to do is specify it as a dependency, but how do you tell it to run the unit test cases with HSQLDB while running the application proper with DB2?!

UPDATE: I've added an hsqldb dependency to pom.xml, re-started the app but it didn't see any difference...

Comment: Add this as an edit to the end of your post, so someone is less likely to miss your comment.

Comment: I'm worried that noone can help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer by reading documentation.